# Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot

Tags: spring, aspectj, maven-3

I am new to AspectJ and Spring and trying to build the example with Maven, given in Appendix A of the book AspectJ In Action. I had to update the Jboss repository setting in to new nexus repository url, in "common-java/pom.xml". Now I'm getting the following error when I do "mvn -e clean package".

Any help is appreciated as I'm clueless how to fix this.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 43.625s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 06 11:21:42 EDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/11M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Commerce: Could not resolve dependencies for project ajia:Commerce:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project Commerce: Could not resolve dependencies for project ajia:Commerce:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project ajia:Commerce:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:170)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:171)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:412)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:164)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:395)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 in org.springsource.maven.snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:945)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)

        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)

        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Tarang,
I have 2 pom.xml files.
1. under my real project named "Commerce" and its contents are:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ajia</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <relativePath>../common-java/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Commerce</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Commerce</name>
</project>
```

1. 2nd inside a folder at the same level as "Commerce" called "common-java"

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                            http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>ajia</groupId>
   <artifactId>common-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>AJIA Common Java POM</name>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <properties>
       <aspectj.version>1.6.5</aspectj.version>
       <spring.version>3.0.0.M4</spring.version>
       <spring-security.version>3.0.0.M2</spring-security.version>
       <spring-batch.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-batch.version>
       <mockito.version>1.8.0</mockito.version>
       <junit.version>4.6</junit.version>
       <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
       <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
       <ejb.version>3.0</ejb.version>
       <hibernate-entitymanager.version>3.4.0.GA</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
       <hibernate.version>3.3.1.GA</hibernate.version>
       <jpa.version>1.0</jpa.version>
       <ognl.version>2.6.7</ognl.version>
       <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.7</hsqldb.version>
       <commons-dbcp.version>1.2.2</commons-dbcp.version>
       <commons-collection.version>3.2.1</commons-collection.version>
       <commons-beanutils.version>1.7.0</commons-beanutils.version>
       <slf4j.version>1.4.2</slf4j.version>
       <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
       <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
       <oscache.version>2.4</oscache.version>
       <cglib.version>2.1_3</cglib.version>
       <dbunit.version>2.4.3</dbunit.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
           <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>quartz</groupId>
                   <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>

       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-instrument-classloading</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
           <version>${spring-batch.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>asm</groupId>
                   <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
               </exclusion>

               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>asm</groupId>
                   <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                   <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
           <version>${jpa.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
           <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
           <version>${jta.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>${jstl.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>${servlet.version}</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
           <version>${ejb.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
           <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
           <version>${commons-collection.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
           <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
           <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
           <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           <version>${log4j.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
           <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
           <version>${oscache.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>${junit.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
           <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
           <version>${mockito.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
           <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>cglib</groupId>
           <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
           <version>${cglib.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
           <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
           <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <testResources>
           <testResource>
               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
           </testResource>
           <testResource>
               <directory>src/test/java</directory>
           </testResource>
       </testResources>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.5</source>
                   <target>1.5</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <additionalProjectnatures>
                       <projectnature>
                           org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature  
                       </projectnature>
                   </additionalProjectnatures>
                   <additionalBuildcommands>
                       <buildcommand>
                           org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder  
                       </buildcommand>
                   </additionalBuildcommands>
                   <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
                   <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                   <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>java</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <phase>deploy</phase>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <mainClass>ajia.main.Main</mainClass>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>org.springsource.maven.snapshot</id>
           <name>SpringSource Maven Central-compatible Milestone Repository</name>
           <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
           <snapshots>
               <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>   
       <repository>
           <id>JBoss repository</id>
           <!--url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url-->
           <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>no</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   ```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Try to use `mvn -e clean package -U`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it but still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out. The nexus URL I had was wrong.
It has to be this URL "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"

Simply did not know how to find that in Nexus!

If anyone wants to browse Nexus use this URL:

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#view-repositories

Answer (score 0):

2 things -

1) Provide your build file.
2) You might need to add the required jar in the dependency tag for the build.